# How to play sound file in a Windows 8 Metro app using WinRT?

Tags: c++, audio, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

The WinRT API surface in Windows 8 seems to have the ability to load and save [Playlists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playlists.playlist%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [capture audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). What I'm looking for is somewhat simpler: does WinRT have the ability to play audio from a file? If not, what's the recommended API for native code (C++) to play audio from a file in a Windows 8 metro app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're in a WWA, you want to use the  HTML tag to play audio. In xaml, you want to use a MediaElement.

If you're using low level C++, you want to use the MediaFoundation APIs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using C++. I found the documentation for MediaFoundation and I'm going to try that. If it works, I'll select this as the accepted answer.

Comment: You may also want to look at the MediaElement, it may be easier to use.

Comment: In this case I'm using C++/WinRT, but not XAML, in a DirectX-based metro app.

Comment: Ah, then you're pretty much stuck with Media Foundation.